# How to index through dynamic generated nested objects in Python?

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk
import tksheet
import json
import pickle


class Treino(object):
    class config(object):
        _list = []
        def __init__(self, name, value):
            self.name = name
            self.value = value
            self._list.append(self)
    class CategoriaTreino(object):
        _list = []
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self._list.append(self)
            self.config = {'RNG': 0}
        class SubCategoriaTreino(object):
            _list = []
            def __init__(self, name, repet):
                self.name = name
                self.repetição = repet
                self._list.append(self)
        pass
def returnCat():
     for cat in TreinoMain.CategoriaTreino._list:
         yield cat
def returnSubCat():
    for subcat in TreinoMain.CategoriaTreino.SubCategoriaTreino._list:
        yield subcat
def savefile():
    with open('treinos.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        for cat in returnCat():
            pickle.dump(cat, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
def loadfile():
    data = []
    with open('treinos.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        while True:
            try:
                data.append(pickle.load(file))
            except EOFError:
                break
    for d in data:
        #iterate through objs
        pass 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TreinoMain = Treino()
    ca1 = TreinoMain.CategoriaTreino("Braço")
    subca1 = ca1.SubCategoriaTreino('Biceps', '2x10')
```

So, code is obviously far from done, my issue though is, i was hoping that creating an instance of the parent object, and then an instance of the child object would allow me to easily return attributes from the child object through it's parent object (and save/load from pickle). but apparently that's not the case (can't reefer to the childobj as parentobj.childobj), any ideas on how to do it in a simple way, or a better way to dynamically generate an object inside another object?
Also i'm almost pretty sure the _list will be useless after i load the objs with pickle and iterate through them...

The idea: Make a GUI so that the user can add/remove categories and subcategories of a data structure on the fly

Why i didn't go with nested data types? I figured it would be easier to implement with objects when i'm actually going to use them for what my goal is (randomize exercise schedules) and to write the add/remove functions.

So far what i've tried was to return attributes with:

```
ca1.subca1.name
```

That doesn't work.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @ScottHunter Basically, "how do people usually handle dynamically generated nested data structures in a way they can easily edit/read them?"